# URL Search for a string with file_get_contents

Tags: php, url, search, download

I am writing a php script that searches a url (http://mp3skull.com/) for the text ".mp3" in hopes of printing the download link to a song as a string. Below is the code that I have so far, it searches the html code of a mp3skull page for ".mp3" and notifies the user if it is successful. The part I need help with: the script needs to be able to find ".mp3" in the webpage source, then print the url/text that comes before it in the source code as a string of plain text. I hope this makes sense and you are able to help me. Thanks.

```
<?php
$filename = 'http://mp3skull.com/mp3/hot_mallets.html';
$searchfor = '.mp3';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
if(strpos($file, $searchfor)) 
{
   echo "String found";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've a feeling as to what you're trying to achieve, although I don't know how to do this exactly, yet doing `echo "$file";` did output `Hello world file.mp3` when using `<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>Hello world <a href="link.xxx">file.mp3</a></body></html>` if that's what you're looking to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for that job. To effectively get those values, use `DOMDocument` + `DOMXpath` instead. Example:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://mp3skull.com/mp3/hot_mallets.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($contents);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$element = $xpath->query('//div[@id="right_song"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
echo $element; //http://incoming.jazz-on-line.com/a/mp3a/VIC041408.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
$filename = 'http://mp3skull.com/mp3/hot_mallets.html';
$searchfor = '.mp3';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($file);
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $property=$a->getAttribute('href');
    if (strpos($property , $searchfor))
        print_r($property);             
            echo "<br/><br/>";
}
?>
```