# How do I get a class name or an id in PHP (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried this in Wordpress:

```
 <?php
if(class_exists('apple')) {
    $option ='apple';
} 
if(class_exists('banana')) {
    $option ='banana';
}else {
    $option ='none';
}
?>  

<div class="apple">
<?echo $option?>
</div>

<div class="banana">
<?echo $option?>
</div>

<div class="none">
<?echo $option?>
</div>
```

But the results are:

"none" , "none" , "none"

How do I get a class name and echo it?
Help me please

Comment: `class_exists()` is used to check if a php [class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) exists, not if a HTML class is present somewhere. What you need is a HTML parser, such as [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)

Comment: I don't want to lose the above form. Is there an alternative to class_exists?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to name a few solutions.

If you generated HTML classes dynamically or something, you could check it there, but other than that you're probably going to need a HTML parser.

You could look for a 'class="apple"' or an 'id="apple"' string within the file.. you could use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or anything similar for that. There's a question for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892554/url-search-for-a-string-with-file-get-contents). (You could then take the value between 'class="' and '"' and wham, you have your class name.)
Now, I'm not saying that's the best way, but it is an option.

Also, you're using [class_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) in your code. I'm afraid that's for something else - it's for checking PHP class existence like this: (← code snippet from the linked documentation)

```
// Check that the class exists before trying to use it
if (class_exists('MyClass')) {
    $myclass = new MyClass();
}
```

Sidenote: This looks like something for a form. If you submited that form, you'd have the value of whatever was selected/checked/pressed/present etc. You'd have to have the classname in their name/value attributes and it would require a submit though..

Hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction :)